# Add Watermark to Capture stream

Tags: c#, directx, directshow

I am using DirectX.Capture and Direct Show.
Using existing project http://www.codeproject.com/KB/directx/directxcapture.aspx?msg=2490488
want to add water mark is it possible? if yes how?

Comment: Thank you for your acceptance of the answer.  Just one note - take care not to spend much time in the drawing, because you can seriously compromise DirectShow clock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a watermark in the recorder video, you would have to insert some watermarking filter into the graph that does capture and recording.  In my apps, I am doing it via [sample grabber filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd407288%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which enables me to access every video frame as it is captured from the input source.

Beware though: the frame will be in some pixel format, and if it's not RGB24 you'll be in a lot of trouble to draw something on it.  If possible, configure your input source to RGB24 and you'll be able to draw on it even with GDI or GDI+.

Expand your question if you need more info.

Comment: Actually, alphablending is always the same. ( (alpha * source) + (255 - alpha) * dest ) >> 8. RGB or YUV. The only "problem" (if we can call it a problem) are values for one pixel. Sometimes in YUV formats they could be scattered all over the buffer :-)